# String of different size for UIButton titlelabel

Tags: ios, swift, uialertaction

I'm trying to bring the title for button action in alert as below

example string in button :
[image]

```
let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
            formattedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Text is small" ,
                                                      attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8.0)]))
            formattedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Text is large"))
```

In UIAlertcontroller action UIButton

```
.addAction(action: AABlurAlertAction(title: formattedString, style: AABlurActionStyle.modern)
```

But it refused to accept the **NSMutableAttributedString** to pass to title argument

Throws error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableAttributedString' to expected argument type 'String?'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try **setAttributedTitle()** instead of **setTitle()**

```
button.setAttributedTitle(formattedString, for: .normal)
```

Comment: You should add to you answer that it's enough to pass `title: nil` in the initializer and then change the title using `setAttributedTitle`. However, `.highlighted` should be also changed. See https://github.com/anas10/AABlurAlertController/blob/master/Source/AABlurAlertController.swift#L65

Comment: I have created two class for two buttons like this...Whether we can make it has one class with different string??    https://iswift.org/playground?SdBoRT&v=3

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to change some code in AABlurAlertAction class

```
self.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

replace this with

```
self.setAttributedTitle(title, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

and replace

```
public init(title: String?, style: AABlurActionStyle, handler: ((AABlurAlertAction) -> Void)?) {
```

with

```
public init(title: NSAttributedString?, style: AABlurActionStyle, handler: ((AABlurAlertAction) -> Void)?) {
```

Comment: I have created two class for two buttons like this...Whether we can make it has one class with different string?? https://iswift.org/playground?SdBoRT&v=3